# Rails 3: page render to preview image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way in rails 3, on server side to render a png or jpg of any given page in my rails app and store it? I'd like to do something like the preview that google uses in the google search when you mouse over the magnifying glass, but only within my app. I'm currently making use of paperclip and imagemagik in my app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only ruby based thing I found was [websnap](http://rubydoc.info/gems/websnap/0.1.3/frames). I never got it to run reliably (especially when there is Flash involved).

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [**IMGkit**](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit)